# Release Notes/History for .NET? Problem with BeginInvoke

Tags: .net, wpf

We have some piece of code that behaves differently in two .NET versions:
  * 3.0.30618  (latest .NET 3.0 version)
  * 3.0.04506  (.NET 3.0 RTM)

It does not work in the RTM version. We traced the problem to a call to system.windows.threading.dispatcher.BeginInvoke. The delegate passed never ran.

Any tips or suggestions for solving this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the problem.

With .NET 3.0 ( 3.0.04506 ), BeginInvoke had the following overloads:

1. Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority,
   Delegate);
2. Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority,
   Delegate, Object);
3. Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority,
   Delegate, Object, Object[]);

With 3.0 SP2 ( 3.0.30618 ), the following were added.

1. Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(Delegate, Object[]);  **<--- we were using this one**
2. Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(Delegate, DispatcherPriority, Object[]);

When ran on a machine with the RTM version of .NET, since the method isn't there yet,
a MissingMethod exception is thrown, so the delegate was never executed.

The solution right now is to use the "old" overload : `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority, Delegate);`

Now, this really sucks. No one can ever use the new overloads and sleep at night.
Now to hunt why the exception was silently handled...

Thanks everyone!

Comment: I don't see why you'd be getting a MissingMethodException... the method's still there isn't it? Confusingly enough, the "old" overloads don't appear in my offline MSDN...

Comment: The method isn't there for there RTM version of .NET. Thats the environment where the delegate was not running.

Answer (score 1):

I strongly *suspect* it's a bug somewhere in your code, even if it *is* a difference between the original .NET 3.0 and a later release.

I suggest you tackle it like any other problem: whittle down your code to the bare minimum to show the problem. Then it should be relatively clear whether it's a framework bug or something wrong in your own code.

Comment: Found the problem (I posted the answer). Now the  bug is somewhere in our code, an exception was silently handled (gasp!).

Answer (score 0):

<strike>The RTM is a early version of the framework. This means it's not entirely stable, and that it's incredibly likely this is a bug. Considering how long .NET 3.0 has been around in release form, my suggestion for solving this 'issue' is quite simply update .NET.</strike>

Ignore this, but I'm going to leave the answer itself so the comments survive.

Comment: My mistake. I didn't know what it stood for, and google wasn't particularly helpful except for a few references in conjunction with betas.